# Custom Client Side Unobtrusive Adapters Validation Method calling Ajax

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, unobtrusive-validation

Unsure if I am going about this the correct way.

I am trying to put in validation for a PersonalID Field on the model that follows some business rules.

The business rule method takes PersonalID as a string and runs through some predetermined checks and returns a bool.

I have created a PersonalIdValidationAttribute that inherits the ValidationAttribute and IClientValidatable.
The IsValid Method calls the business rule to determine if the PersonalID is indeed valid.

This all seems to be working as intended. If I turn of client side validation, the model validation on POSTing works as supposed to.

The GetClientValidationRules seems to be working as well. Here is the code:

```
public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        var rule = new ModelClientValidationRule()
        {
            // Test Error Message
            ErrorMessage = "An Error",
            ValidationType = "personalidvalidation"
        };

        yield return rule;
    }
```

It is also creating the input field with the data-val as I would expect:

```
<input class="input valid" data-val="true" data-val-length="Rajoitus 30 merkkiä" data-val-length-max="11" data-val-personalidvalidation="An Error" data-val-required="Henkilötunnus on pakollinen" id="PolicyHolder_PersonalID" name="PolicyHolder.PersonalID" type="text" value="">
```

Now I am unsure is if I am allowed to do this. Within the script file, I am adding the Client Side validation:

```
$.validator.addMethod("personalidvalidation", function (value, element, params) {
        var record = { personalID: value };
        return $.ajax({
            url: "PersonalIdValidation",
            data: JSON.stringify(record),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.success) {
                    console.log('success');
                    return true;
                } else {
                    console.log('fail');
                    return false;
                }
            },
            error: function () {
                return false;
            }
        });
    });

    $.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("personalidvalidation", function (options) {
        options.rules["personalidvalidation"] = options.params;
        options.messages["personalidvalidation"] = options.message;
    });
```

Looking at the Network tab in developer console shows the controller method is being called but the validation message is never shown correctly. Both the success and fail messages are shown in the console.

How do I call the controller with the business logic to do client side validation on the PersonalID?

Thank you in advance.